# Есть ли возможность написать чат-бот на Facebook, аналогичный создаваемым для Telegram?

Tags: python, facebook

Есть ли python библиотеки, аналогичные aiogram или pytelegrambotapi для Facebook?
Гугл предлагает Flask, но может быть существуют еще альтернативы?

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook_PyBot](https://pypi.org/project/Facebook_PyBot/) .
Так же могу порекомендовать
https://pypi.org/search/?q=facebook&o= для выбора необходимых библиотек , согласно вашим критериям.